# Finding a word and copying the line it's in in Java

Tags: java, text-files

I'm trying to create a small program that allows you to search for a word in a text file, and then the program should print out the whole line the text is in.

Example:

```
test.txt
   don't mind this text
   don't mind this either
```

and then when you let the program search for the word "text", it should print out "Don't mind this text".

What's the best way to do this?

This is what I have;

```
public boolean findFileInCache(){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("direct.txt"))) 
        {
            while ((name = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(name);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e1) {    }   

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Actually attempting it is usually the best way to go about writing a program.

Comment: Christopher, I know, I'm actually trying things as well. I just can't seem to get anywhere after trying since yesterday

Comment: What do you have so far ? What have you done ? Do you have a specific problem ? Normally, you should have a specific question that we can answer.

Comment: Have you read in the file so far?

Comment: Updated post with the code I got, it reads into the file but I need it to only use the line the word I searched for is in

Comment: I can't imagine why you thought `Process` might be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to read the file line by line using the [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method.

For each line, check if the word is in it using a regular expression, or by splitting the line into a `String[]` (using [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)), and iterating the entries in the resulting array to check if any of them is the desired word. If the desired word is there - print the entire line.

If you chose the 2nd suggestion, don't forget to check equality of two strings by using `equals()` and NOT by using `==`

Comment: Excellent. Provide all the information and let them piece it together. +1

Comment: Indeed, I prefer it when I can put the pieces together! +1 and accepted as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you need to do:

1. Learn the basics by going through an introductory Java book, or course notes, from the beginning, making sure you understand each step as it comes.
2. Read the Javadocs of likely classes, to find methods that could be useful for the task.

You have already found two core pieces of the solution:

- You are getting a line at a time using `BufferedReader.readLine()`
- You are doing it in a `while` loop, so you handle one line at a time

Now, you need to work out how to deal with each line. Although you didn't include the type, `name` is a String. It would be better as:

```
 while ((String name = br.readLine()) != null) {
      ... do something with `line`
 }
```

If your code compiled without `String` there, it means you declared `name` as a global. Don't do that, until you know what you're doing.

Breaking things into methods is good; so let's make "do something with `line`" use a method now:

```
 while ((String name = br.readLine()) != null) {
      if(matches(line,"text")) {
           System.out.println(line);
      }
 }
```

Now you need to write `matches()`:

```
 private boolean matches(String line, String word) {
      boolean result = // work out whether it's a match
      return result;
 }
```

So, how do you write the guts of `matches()`?

Well, start by looking at the methods available in `String`. It has methods like `contains()` and `split()`. Some of those methods return other types, like arrays. Your teaching material and reference materials tell you how to look in arrays. The answers are there.